# Execution Time and Space Of a Program

Tags: node.js

how to print time and space of a program [like java code, c++ code] in node js? On competitive coding platform like LeetCode  the platform prints the information like execution time and space usage after completion of the execution of a program.

How we can achieve same functionality in Node JS?

[image]

Comment: Go through the nodejs `process` documentation. Specifically https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#processmemoryusage

Comment: Define timing. You can use built-in Javascript console time features.